# AngularJS throwing error when getting length of empty input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently trying to validate a card with AngularJS. This works fine until the user deletes all the inputted data from the input field, then it throws the following errors:

```
angular.js:11004 undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.card.length')
```

My HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" class='form-control' id='card' ng-model="card" ng-change="validateCard()" required>
```

JavaScript code that throws the error when the input is empty:

```
$scope.validateCard = function() {
    // Get card type
    if ($scope.card.length) { // <-- throws the error
        [...]
```

I also tried

```
if ($scope.card.length !== undefined) {
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: `$scope.card` might as well be undefined. `if($scope.card && $scope.card.length)` maybe?

Comment: `if ($scope.card && $scope.card.length) ...`

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you cannot take length of `undefined` value. You could use something like this:

```
if ($scope.card && $scope.card.length) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for both using && condition

```
$scope.validateCard = function() {
   if ($scope.card && $scope.card.length) { 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check that your item is defined:

```
if (angular.isDefined($scope.card) && $scope.card.length) { }
```